# When Directory.EnumerateFiles throws an exception what path is throwing it?

Tags: .net

This applies to all the `EnumerateFiles` and `EnumerateDirectories` methods in the `System.IO` namespace really.

Assume the following code, based loosely from the Microsoft documentation for [Directory.EnumerateFiles Method (String)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383458(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
try
{
  var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(sourceDirectory);

  foreach (var file in files)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("{0}", file);
  }
}
catch (UnauthorizedAccessException UAEx)
{
  Console.WriteLine(UAEx.Message);
}
catch (PathTooLongException PathEx)
{
  Console.WriteLine(PathEx.Message);
}
```

When the exceptions here are caught, is it because of `sourceDirectory`, or `file`?

Comment: Did you try debugging to see which line threw the exception?

Comment: Exception reporting shows it on the foreach line.
It's not running where I can attach a debugger, and I can't figure out a way to fake/mock it with tests.

Comment: In your code example you never take an action against the file.  So all errors would be at the directory level.  The act of getting the file list is at the directory level.   If you took an action against a file (like rename) then you would see a file level error.

Comment: It may well be that due to deferred execution of the call to `EnumerateFiles` method means that exceptions don't occur until you try to access members of the `files` collection. An example of deferred exection and exception handling can be seen [here](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/LinqDeferredExceptions.aspx). I'm not suggesting you follow that approach, but it'll give you an idea of what might be happening. Like the documentation you referenced implies, if you aren't working with a large number of files, maybe look at the GetFiles to avoid deferred execution.

Comment: It can be both.  Files normally inherit their ACL from the directory but they are securable objects themselves.  And the directory path may not exceed MAXDIR but the file might trip MAXPATH.  If you get any file before it bombs then you know it is a file, but if it keels over right away then you don't know.  IT staff normally first investigates the directory since it is by far the most likely troublemaker.